# 500 Internal Server Error FB.Feed

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook SDK 6.0 for Unity.

## I tried to put in my link in a Feed then error comes up.

```
500 Internal Server Error
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost:CallbackWithErrorHandling(FBResult)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

===
Even if you try with InteractiveConsole (demo scene).

The only way to make it works is Feed link MUST be "http://facebook.com". Any other link will lead to the above error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue, but turns out the other URLs I was trying were just "invalid".  That is, the URLs must be valid and available to the general public (no login required).  I was trying to use the URL for my Facebook Canvas app, but since it was still in testing mode, it isn't available to the general public yet.  I was also using some URLs on my company website, but I hadn't actually created the pages yet.

Maybe not your problem, but I hate when people post "answers" as comments, because then you cannot accept it if it was a valid answer and the question stays open... so here you go.

Comment: Also, I haven't got any actionLink URLs to work yet, but I assume those can only be valid canvas URLs, or maybe URLs to other special items.  My answer is related to the main "link" field.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue trying to Feed on facebook with an image and caption and link and all that stuff.

I'm using Facebook SDK 6 for Unity.

I get a solution by calling the FB.Feed() with ALL the params even if they were ""... something like this:

```
public void ShareMessageWithGameLink(string _linkName, string _linkToPicture, string _linkCaption, string _link, string _description, Action<string> callback)
    {
        FB.Feed(
            toId: "",
            link: _link,
            linkName: _linkName,
            linkCaption: _linkCaption,
            linkDescription: _description,
            picture: _linkToPicture,
            actionName : "",
            actionLink : "",
            reference : "",
            callback: PostResponse
            );
    }
```

This worked for me... Hope this work for you as well!